# How to read first line of a file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, filereader

In JavaSctipt the FileReader object doesn't seem to have support for just reading the first line of a file. (up to the CR '\n'). I dont want to read in the whole file to save memory.

Is there a way to do it?

My code (note that readLine() function does not exists):

```
    self.loadFirstLineFromFile = function (options, callback) {
        var hiddenElement = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenElement.id = 'hidden-tsv-file-loader';
        hiddenElement.type = 'file';
        hiddenElement.accept = options.extension;
        hiddenElement.style.display = 'none';
        hiddenElement.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
            var file = event.target.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader(file);
            var firstLine;
            firstLine = reader.readLine();
            callback(firstLine);
        });
        document.body.appendChild(hiddenElement);
        hiddenElement.click();
    };
```

Comment: Could you precise what is a line for you? A line must be delimited by an ending caracter (carrier return(CR), line feed(LF) OR your own delimiter). This is what you should look to determine when your function meet the end of a line

Comment: The browser APIs do not themselves provide for any particular file structure.

Comment: Yes, first string up to the CR. \n
I want to save memory and check the file header before reading in all the contents.

Comment: Small pedantic remark: `'\n'` is a line feed (LF), `'\r` is a carriage return (CR)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing builtin for that, but it's simple to implement:

```js
var file = event.target.files[0];
var sliced = file.slice(0, 2048); // Pick a size that you're ok with
// NOTE: `await` keyword requires transpiling (Babel) for IE11,
// and to be inside an async function. An alternative is:
// sliced.text().then(function(text) { console.log(text); });
var text = await sliced.text();
console.log(text);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't just read the first line. It reads in *everything* (even if it is a multi-gigabyte log file) and then extracts the first line from it afterwards.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to avoid! Is there a way to save memory and just read one line?

Comment: Hi Quentin! I'm not sure if event.target.files[0] will somehow contain a partial file (the browser may have already read in the whole multi-gigabytes of logs), but I updated with an alternative that could limit the size of the data handled by trhis function.

Comment: Hi Michael! I'm not sure if you can save memory yourself - the browser may have already prepared the "File" object for you with the complete contents.

Comment: @boxmein no it hasn't. A blob is not a block of memory, it is a reference to a block of memory. The data it's referencing does not necessarily have to be buffered, and for a `File` specifically, it almost certainly is not buffered. That's the reason you have to `await` when you call `.text()` because it's resolving the reference during that time and may involve reading contents from disk.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interface that reads the data from the `Blob` decoded as text and chunked by a `delimiter`:

```
async function* readLines (blob, encoding = 'utf-8', delimiter = /\r?\n/g) {
  const reader = blob.stream().getReader();
  const decoder = new TextDecoder(encoding);

  try {
    let text = '';

    while (true) {
      const { value, done } = await reader.read();

      if (done) break;

      text += decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });

      const lines = text.split(delimiter);

      text = lines.pop();
      yield* lines;
    }

    yield text;
  } finally {
    reader.cancel();
  }
}
```

We can use this to read a single line and discard the rest without reading the entire file:

```
hiddenElement.addEventListener('change', async function (event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];

  for await (const line of readLines(file, 'utf-8', '\n')) {
    callback(line);
    return; // signals reader.cancel() to the async iterator
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I use Javascript with Knockout I refactored Patricks solution into this:

```
 self.loadStream = function (options, callback) {
        var hiddenElement = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenElement.id = 'hidden-tsv-file-loader';
        hiddenElement.type = 'file';
        hiddenElement.accept = options.extension;
        hiddenElement.style.display = 'none';
        hiddenElement.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
            var file = event.target.files[0];
            var reader = file.stream().getReader();
            var decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
            var data;

            var readNextChunk = function () {
                data = reader.read();
                data.then(function (result) {
                    if (!result.value) {
                        callback({ chunk: '', done: true, shouldStop: true }, file);
                    } else {
                        var chunk = decoder.decode(result.value, { stream: true });
                        var args = {
                            chunk: chunk,
                            done: result.done,
                            shouldStop: true
                        };
                        callback(args, file);
                        if (!result.done && !args.shouldStop) {
                            readNextChunk();
                        }
                    }
                });
            };

            readNextChunk();
            hiddenElement.remove();
        });
        document.body.appendChild(hiddenElement);
        hiddenElement.click();
    };
```